# Handler cannot be converted to View

Tags: java, android

i have a question! Why is my paramView = new Handler(); in red? My error log is `error: incompatible types: Handler cannot be converted to View`.
How can i fix it?

```
    public void startTimer(final View paramView)
    {
        paramView = new Handler();
        Timer localTimer = new Timer();
        this.timerTask = new TimerTask()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                paramView.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        ((TextView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(MainActivity.this.myTimer + "");
                        MainActivity localMyActivity = MainActivity.this;
                        localMyActivity.myTimer += 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        localTimer.schedule(this.timerTask, 0L, 10L);
    }
```

Please help me to fix the Problem

Comment: because Handler and View are two different classes! what exactly are u trying to do here? why are you passing paramView in startTimer() method as parameter?

Comment: I'd like to bild an app, where you can Tap ten times and the timer scores the seconds. Sorry, for my bad english!

Comment: You literally just need to remove this line: `paramView = new Handler();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of `paramView = new Handler();`. Of course you can't assign a Handler to a View. And it this case you don't need a Handler either. View has the `post` method, that adds the `Runnable` to the message queue. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) you can find the documentation

Comment: How do I this? I don't know how!

Comment: just delete `paramView = new Handler();` and the error will disappear. The rest looks good

Comment: Ok, I had all paramView... deleted. But now, in an other public void my setText is red

Comment: And in an other public void is paramView now red. Now it showes me: Cannot assign a value to final variable 'paramView'

Answer (score 0):

```
paramView = new Handler();
```

This is wrong becuase paramView is a `View`, not a handler. A View cannot be cast to a `Handler`, nor do they have anything in common so to speak. One is used to show something on the UI, the other on to do something.